# How can I tell gcc not to inline a function?

Tags: c, gcc, inline

Say I have this small function in a source file

```
static void foo() {}
```

and I build an optimized version of my binary yet I don't want this function inlined (for optimization purposes). is there a macro I can add in a source code to prevent the inlining?

Comment: Thanks for this question! I was profiling with oprofile when a function did not show up, the answers here fixed this.

Comment: c++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329214/is-it-possible-to-force-a-function-not-to-be-inlined

Answer (score 192, accepted):

You want the `gcc`-specific [`noinline`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) attribute.

> This function attribute prevents a
>   function from being considered for
>   inlining. If the function does not
>   have side-effects, there are
>   optimizations other than inlining that
>   causes function calls to be optimized
>   away, although the function call is
>   live. To keep such calls from being
>   optimized away, put
>             `asm ("");`

Use it like this:

```
void __attribute__ ((noinline)) foo() 
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Using gcc 4.4.3 on Arch Linux, I get a syntax error with the attribute placed as above.  It works correctly when it precedes the function (e.g., __attribute__ ((noinline)) void foo() {})

Comment: Arduino also wanted it placed before the function.

Comment: Edited to fix the attribute syntax.

Comment: The asm("") construct is actually fairly cross-platform and got the job done.  I did it for x86 Linux and it did not cause a build problem on PowerPC AIX.  Thanks for this useful suggestion!

Comment: Using gcc 6.2.1 on Arch Linux, no problem.

Comment: Just curious, Does using extern keyword For e,g extern void foo(); has the same effect as noinline attribute.

Comment: The approach which requires code changes everywhere cannot be reasonably considered an acceptable answer.

Comment: @ajeh - I thinks its another instance of the compiler turning a working program into a non-working one. Maybe you can plead your case to GCC. (I'm happy there was a solution to [Labels in GCC inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3898435/608639), where the optimizer duplicated our inline ASM and caused multiple symbols with the same name).

Comment: Does this work in all cases, or is it like the `inline` keyword where the compiler can ignore it?

Answer (score 47):

GCC has a switch called

`-fno-inline-small-functions`

So use that when invoking gcc. But the side effect is that all other small functions are also non-inlined.

Comment: Didn't work at compiler level.
Was using gcc 5.2.1 20150902 (Red Hat 5.2.1-2)

Comment: Either current GCC 6.4 is broken, or this and simpler `-fno-inline` do not work at all. `gdb` still enters methods on step-over. Something is broken, and I doubt it is `gdb`.

Comment: It will turn off inline optimization for all, not only for a specified function.

Comment: @ajeh Not inlining functions means that they are called normally, doesn’t it?

Answer (score 30):

I know the question is about GCC, but I thought it might be useful to
have some information about compilers other compilers as well.

GCC's
[`noinline`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)
function attribute is pretty popular with other compilers as well. It
is supported by at least:

- Clang (check with `__has_attribute(noinline)`)
- Intel C/C++ Compiler (their documentation is terrible, but I'm
  certain it works on 16.0+)
- Oracle Solaris Studio back to at least 12.2
- ARM C/C++ Compiler back to at least 4.1
- IBM XL C/C++ back to at least 10.1
- TI 8.0+ (or 7.3+ with --gcc, which will define `__TI_GNU_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORT__`)

Additionally, MSVC supports
[`__declspec(noinline)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/noinline)
back to Visual Studio 7.1. Intel probably supports it too (they try to
be compatible with both GCC and MSVC), but I haven't bothered to
verify that. The syntax is basically the same:

```
__declspec(noinline)
static void foo(void) { }
```

PGI 10.2+ (and probably older) supports a `noinline` pragma which
applies to the next function:

```
#pragma noinline
static void foo(void) { }
```

TI 6.0+ supports a
[`FUNC_CANNOT_INLINE`](http://downloads.ti.com/docs/esd/SPRUI04/index.html#SPRUI04B_HTML/tms320c6000-c-c-language-implementation.html#7.9.10_The_FUNC_CANNOT_INLINE_Pragma%3FTocPath%3D7%2520TMS320C6000%2520C%252FC%252B%252B%2520Language%2520Implementation%7C7.9%2520Pragma%2520Directives%7C_____16)
pragma which (annoyingly) works differently in C and C++. In C++, it's similar to PGI's:

```
#pragma FUNC_CANNOT_INLINE;
static void foo(void) { }
```

In C, however, the function name is required:

```
#pragma FUNC_CANNOT_INLINE(foo);
static void foo(void) { }
```

Cray 6.4+ (and possibly earlier) takes a similar approach, requiring
the function name:

```
#pragma _CRI inline_never foo
static void foo(void) { }
```

Oracle Developer Studio also supports a pragma which takes the
function name, going back to [at least Forte Developer
6](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/fortec6u2/806-7984/806-7984.pdf),
but note that it needs to come *after* the declaration, even in recent
versions:

```
static void foo(void);
#pragma no_inline(foo)
```

Depending on how dedicated you are, you could create a macro that
would work everywhere, but you would need to have the function name as
well as the declaration as arguments.

If, OTOH, you're okay with something that just works for most people,
you can get away with something which is a little more aesthetically
pleasing and doesn't require repeating yourself. That's the approach
I've taken for [Hedley](https://nemequ.github.io/hedley/), where the
current version of
[HEDLEY_NEVER_INLINE](https://nemequ.github.io/hedley/api-reference.html#HEDLEY_NEVER_INLINE)
looks like:

```
#if \
  HEDLEY_GNUC_HAS_ATTRIBUTE(noinline,4,0,0) || \
  HEDLEY_INTEL_VERSION_CHECK(16,0,0) || \
  HEDLEY_SUNPRO_VERSION_CHECK(5,11,0) || \
  HEDLEY_ARM_VERSION_CHECK(4,1,0) || \
  HEDLEY_IBM_VERSION_CHECK(10,1,0) || \
  HEDLEY_TI_VERSION_CHECK(8,0,0) || \
  (HEDLEY_TI_VERSION_CHECK(7,3,0) && defined(__TI_GNU_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORT__))
#  define HEDLEY_NEVER_INLINE __attribute__((__noinline__))
#elif HEDLEY_MSVC_VERSION_CHECK(13,10,0)
#  define HEDLEY_NEVER_INLINE __declspec(noinline)
#elif HEDLEY_PGI_VERSION_CHECK(10,2,0)
#  define HEDLEY_NEVER_INLINE _Pragma("noinline")
#elif HEDLEY_TI_VERSION_CHECK(6,0,0)
#  define HEDLEY_NEVER_INLINE _Pragma("FUNC_CANNOT_INLINE;")
#else
#  define HEDLEY_NEVER_INLINE HEDLEY_INLINE
#endif
```

If you don't want to use Hedley (it's a single public domain / CC0
header) you can convert the version checking macros without too much
effort, but more than I'm willing to put in ☺.

Comment: Thanks for the link to your project @nemequ. I've asked our other developers to evaluate it for our use. We have diverse architectures.

Comment: I'd be very interested to know what they say, *especially* if they're not interested.  And, of course, I'm around to answer questions (GitHub issue tracker, e-mail, whatever…).

Answer (score 22):

A portable way to do this is to call the function through a pointer:

```
void (*foo_ptr)() = foo;
foo_ptr();
```

Though this produces different instructions to branch, which may not be your goal.  Which brings up a good point: what *is* your goal here?

Comment: If the pointer is defined at file scope, and not static, it should work since the compiler then can't assume it has its initial value at time of use. If it's a local (as shown) it's almost certainly treated the same as foo(). ("In this decade", he added, looking at the dates)

Comment: This will not work on modern compilers (e.g. gcc 11, clang 12): they will see right through this and inline the function anyway: https://godbolt.org/z/hh8dcnE3v Adding `volatile` makes it work again.

Comment: downvoted since as previous comment says: this is not reliable in all cases.

Answer (score 15):

In case you get a compiler error for `__attribute__((noinline))`, you can just try:

```
noinline int func(int arg)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
static __attribute__ ((noinline))  void foo()
{

}
```

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `noinline` [attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

```
int func(int arg) __attribute__((noinline))
{
}
```

You should probably use it both when you declare the function for external use and when you write the function.

Answer (score 2):

I work with gcc 7.2.  I specifically needed a function to be non-inlined, because it had to be instantiated in a library.  I tried the `__attribute__((noinline))` answer, as well as the `asm("")` answer. Neither one solved the problem.

Finally, I figured that defining a static variable inside the function will force the compiler to allocate space for it in the static variable block, and to issue an initialization for it when the function is first called.

This is sort of a dirty trick, but it works.

Comment: You could define your function `inline void foo(void) { ... }` in a header and declare it `extern inline void foo(void);` in a library source file. Following C99 semantics, the compiler would be allowed to inline the function when it pleases AND emit object code in your library. See [Is "inline" without "static" or "extern" ever useful in C99 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312597/is-inline-without-static-or-extern-ever-useful-in-c99).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get `__attribute__((noinline))` to work, but this works on clang and GCC.

The Linux kernel defines `noinline`.

```
include/linux/compiler_attributes.h:#define noinline __attribute__((__noinline__))
```

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
static noinline void foo(void);
```