# How do I force a function to be created in Release mode on Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to force a function not to be inlined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329214/is-it-possible-to-force-a-function-not-to-be-inlined)

I have this class method that doesn't actually get created due to optimization in Release mode on Visual C++( the function simply gets "embedded" in the caller function, without having a proper prolog and epilog ). How do I tell the compiler to create a standalone function?

Comment: "inlined" is the term usually used (as opposed to "embedded")

Comment: Answered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329214/is-it-possible-to-force-a-function-not-to-be-inlined

Comment: @Rhuidean Thank you. please vote to close the question.

Comment: Why do you need this? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `pragma` in VC++

```
#pragma auto_inline(off)

void non_inlined_func() { /* ... */ }

#pragma auto_inline() // returns to previous state
```

See [the documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah08w5c3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

That's called an `inline` function. If you're linking against that module, you can move the implementation to a `cpp` file, so it's not visible outside. That way, any modules trying to use it will have to call it.

You can also disable set the compiler flag "inline function expansion" to `Only __inline (/Ob1)` to prevent `inlining` in the current module, assuming you're not marking it as `inline`.

Or use:

```
#pragma auto_inline(off)
void foo()
{
}
#pragma auto_inline()
```

#### EDIT:

I listed my first variant first as that's the proper way to do it. You should let the optimizer do what it can to speed up your code. It shouldn't matter to you if it's inlined in your own module (or others, for that matter, since the assembled code is still visible in your binary), but if you really must do it, choose the first option.