# disable function optimization c++

Tags: c++, inline

I am a student in the Hebrew University and I am trying to measure the time of calling an empty function without optimization using c++. I understand that unrolling loop may help me get an accurate result but my problem is that is the compiler might convert the function to inline function and I want to prevent it from happening. I know that I can "hint" the compiler not do so by using volatile key word but that it may ignore this request.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you consulted some techniques like inlining: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474030/how-can-i-tell-gcc-not-to-inline-a-function

+ -O0 compiler flag?

Comment: Put the function in a separate translation unit (compile it separately).

Comment: Analyze the assembly code to see if the function call is still there.

Comment: This may depend on the compiler you use: AFAIK, MSVC++ does not consider any `inline` in Debug mode. (Otherwise, step in/step out and local variables probably wouldn't work.) (About g++ or other compilers I don't know.)